# Google cloud OSError: SavedModel file does not exist

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, tf.keras

I have machine learning project wrapped with a `Flask` app and deployed on `Google cloud`. which contains `h5` type trained model on my `app` directory. I'm trying to load that saved model to a file like below.

```
model = load_model('trained_model.h5', custom_objects={'AttentionLayer' : attn_layer})
```

But it gives the following error

```
OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: trained_model.h5/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}
```

also I tried with absolute path like this

```
model_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'app', 'trained_model.h5')
model = load_model(model_path, custom_objects={'AttentionLayer' : attn_layer})
```

But still I'm getting this error.

I tried changing the path and almost all solutions in here but nothing works for me. Is there any solution for this?